# How to debug apollo query initiated in server Side

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-js

js (node) server and using @apollo/client v3.
I need to know how can i debug/inspect the queries request from the server.

The actual motivation behind this discussion is

I am requesting a query to a third party graphql server
there is something wrong with my requested query as it has multiple Fragments so i need to inspect what is the resolved
query before the graphql makes the request.

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9631

Github issue for reference

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [custom link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/) in your Apollo Client code
2. Inspect or `console.log()` the [operation object](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#the-operation-object) in your custom link
3. `operation.query` will contain the parsed gql code
4. `operation.variables` will contain the gql variables